# How to show the limit is $\log(2)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Show that limit of string $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\ \geq\ 1}$ is $\log\left(2\right)$, where
> $$
> a_{n} = \int_{1/\left(2n\right)}^{1/n}
> {\mathrm{e}^x \over x}\,\mathrm{d}x
> $$.

My approach: It's easy to show that using
$\mathrm{e}^{x} \geq x + 1$ and you got right side.
But what about left side ?. Any ideas ?. $\ldots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  Bounding the Exponential Function**

If we use the inequalities $1+x\le e^x\le \frac1{1-x}$, for $x<1$, we have for $n>1$

$$\int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n}\frac{1+x}{x}\,dx\le \int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n}\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx\le \int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n}\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\,dx$$

---

**HINT:**

**METHODOLOGY $2$:  Integrating by Parts**

Using integration by parts, note that we have

$$\int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n} \frac{e^x}{x}\,dx=\log(1/n)e^{1/n}-\log(1/(2n))e^{1/(2n)}-\int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n}\log(x)e^x\,dx$$

Now show that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\log(1/n)e^{1/n}-\log(1/(2n))e^{1/(2n)}\right)=\log(2)$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/(2n)}^{1/n}\log(x)e^x\,dx=0$$

---

Comment: +1. Did you get the estimation $e^x \leq \frac{1}{1-x}$ by the classical $e^x \geq 1+x$ used with $-x$ instead of $x$ and then taking the reciprocal (so imposing $1-x>0$ for having positive terms on both sides of the inequality)? Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Thank you.  Much appreciated.  And yes.  We have $e^x\ge 1+x$ for all $x$.  Then, $e^{-x}\ge 1-x$.   Now for $x<1$, $1-x>0$.  Hence, we have $e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$e^{1/2n}(1/x) < e^x/x <e^{1/n}(1/x);$

$e^{1/2n}\displaystyle{\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}}(1/x) dx < \int_{1/2n}^{1/n}(e^x/x) dx < e^{1/n}\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}(1/x) dx$

Used: Monotony of Riemann integrals.

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure as to the reason that this hasn't received more up votes.

Comment: Never mind, it has been upvoted once:) Thanks.

Comment: You are now wrong ! Twice. Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude. Thanks:) Hope you are well. Stay safe.Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Using $\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$, you will get $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1/n}^{1/2n} \left( \frac{1}{x}+1+\cdots \right) dx=\log 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer different from $ 0 $ :

Notice that $ x\mapsto\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}{x} $ is continuous on $ \left(0,+\infty\right) $, and can be extended to a continuous function on $ \left[0,+\infty\right) $, which is the reason why it is integrable on any segment $ \left[0,a\right] $, where $ a\geq 0 $.

\begin{aligned}\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\ln{2}\\ &=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\ln{2}\\ &=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{y}{2}}-1}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ \int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{2}}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\ln{2}\end{aligned}

Notice that in the third line we substituted $ x=\frac{y}{2}\cdot $

Since $ x\mapsto\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{2}}}{x} $ is also a continuous function on $ \left(0,+\infty\right) $, and can be extended to a continuous function on $ \left[0,+\infty\right) $, it can be upper-bounded on $ \left[0,1\right] $ by some constant $ M\geq 0 \cdot $

Thus : $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}-\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{2}}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\leq\frac{M}{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Hence : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{\int_{\frac{1}{2n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}}=\ln{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can integrate Taylor expansions, more precisely

if $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n+o(x^n)$

then $F(x)=F(0)+a_0X+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}+o(x^{n+1})$

Using $e^x=1+x+o(x)$ we get $\frac{e^x}{x}=\frac 1x+1+o(1)$ with a term $\frac 1x$ not verifying the conditions.

But simply set $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1+o(1)$ and you can apply the theorem.

And get $\displaystyle\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}\frac{e^x}{x}\mathop{dx}=\int_{1/2n}^{1/n}\frac{1}{x}\mathop{dx}+\frac 1{2n}+o\left(\frac 1n\right)\to\ln 2$

The reason being that it's just inequalities in disguise (i.e. $|o(1)|<\varepsilon$ for $n\gg 1$).